# JS: отдельный файл или встраиваемый скрипт

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Что есть сейчас?** Сейчас есть страницы назовем ее калькуляторами (в большинстве случаев каждый на отдельной странице, но есть и по 2 на одной), на которой есть поля input со значениями по умолчанию и кнопка "Посчитать" (для кнопки задан разный класс для разных калькуляторов), есть подгружаемый файл `custom.js` в котором весь код для всех калькуляторов и при помощи jQuery в зависимости от того, какая кнопка нажата идут разные расчеты для разных калькуляторов и потом выводятся на странице в виде таблицы.

**Сейчас нужно сделать**, чтобы при загрузке страницы были результаты расчетов из input, в которых есть значения по умолчанию. Также при изменении значений в input автоматически производился перерасчет. Возникает вопрос как правильнее сделать?!

Я сейчас вижу два варианта:

1) Дублировать расчеты на страницу калькулятора, а в `custom.j`s оставить только для `on('change')`

2) На странице калькулятора создавать переменную и давать ей к примеру название тайтла страницы, в custom.js проверять если эта переменная равна такому то тайтлу значит делаем нужные расчеты, пихаем их в какую-то функцию и по  `on('change')` пересчитываем результаты

3) Ваш вариант :)

Ниже приведен код для примера, сами формулы там сложнее.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  
  $('input').on('change', function() {
    var field1 = parseFloat($('.field1').val());
    var field2 = parseFloat($('.field2').val());
    
    var sum = field1 + field2;
    
    $('.results').html(sum);
    
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type"number" class="field1" value="100">
<input type"number" class="field2" value="200">

<div class="results"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Дать всем кнопкам еще один одинаковый класс:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  ...      
  $('.buttonClass').click();
});
```

Comment: но тогда перед этим нужно расчет сделать и вывести результат как только страница загрузится, а потом при изменении снова пересчитать